# Sending email using corporate exchange server in c#

Tags: c#

I have searched on internet but couldn't found reliable answer.I want to send email in c# using my corporate exchange server.Could any one describe how is it possible and what information i need to send emails?? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to start reading about the [EWS Managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx). The page at the link has detailed steps how to enable your C# app to send an email using exchange.

Comment: Is it an Outlook exchange?  An outlook exchange use Network Credentials.  So you must have a local outlook account setup on the PC.  Network credentials uses the encrypted password stored locally for the user outlook account as the password to login to the corporate exchange.  The network credentials sends the credentials and email securely so it cannot be hacked.  The email is then sent through a proxy server to the exchange server using port forwarding since normal smtp ports are usually blocked by firewalls in corporate networks.

Comment: Will it work for google exchange server.

Comment: @Quadeer Hussain. I don't know, I used it to connect to an on premises exchange server.